# How to remove all integer values from a list in python

Tags: python, string

I am just a beginner in python and I want to know is it possible to remove all the integer values from a list? For example the document goes like

```
['1','introduction','to','molecular','8','the','learning','module','5']
```

After the removal I want the document to look like:

```
['introduction','to','molecular','the','learning','module']
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To remove all integers, do this:

```
no_integers = [x for x in mylist if not isinstance(x, int)]
```

However, your example list does not actually contain integers.  It contains only strings, some of which are composed only of digits.  To filter those out, do the following:

```
no_integers = [x for x in mylist if not (x.isdigit() 
                                         or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

Alternately:

```
is_integer = lambda s: s.isdigit() or (s[0] == '-' and s[1:].isdigit())
no_integers = filter(is_integer, mylist)
```

Comment: if you want to modify the list in-place rather than create a list, this can be done with simple loop.

Comment: @mykhal Just checking, is that a joke? It does work on multi-digit numbers, of course

Comment: @razpetia: Fixed to handle negative numbers

Comment: The generalizations make this much less clear. Try S. Lott's more Pythonic answer instead.

Comment: @Daniel Stutzbach: Your filtering function is great but you should've used filter(). Keep it pythonic, y'know ..

Comment: @Brian: It is not at clear to me that the original poster needs (or wants) to filter hexadecimal.

Comment: @Daniel: True, but if you're going to complain about not handling negative numbers, you can complain about this, too.  It also doesn't handle '+5'.

Comment: This answer also won't handle '  4' or '4 ' or the like.

Comment: Isn't there like any method for that in core Python? e.g. list.delete(obj_type)?

Comment: The ALTERNATIVE results in an filter-object.
Use list(no_integers) to get back an list-objekt.

And it results in ONLY THE NUMBERS.
To get the list without the numbers use:
is_not_integer = lambda s: not s.isdigit() and not (s[0] == '-' and s[1:].isdigit())

Answer (score 14):

None of the items in your list are integers. They are strings which contain only digits. So you can use the `isdigit` string method to filter out these items.

```
items = ['1','introduction','to','molecular','8','the','learning','module','5']

new_items = [item for item in items if not item.isdigit()]

print new_items
```

Link to documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Answer (score 13):

You can do this, too:

```
def int_filter( someList ):
    for v in someList:
        try:
            int(v)
            continue # Skip these
        except ValueError:
            yield v # Keep these

list( int_filter( items ))
```

Why?  Because `int` is better than trying to write rules or regular expressions to recognize string values that encode an integer.

Comment: Why is `int` better than `str.isdigit`, though?

Comment: As others have pointed out, `'-2'.isdigit()` will return `False`.

Comment: +1.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/checking-if-string-is-a-number-python for discussion (with `float`, but still just as relevant).

Answer (score 5):

I personally like filter. I think it can help keep code readable and conceptually simple if used in a judicious way:

```
x = ['1','introduction','to','molecular','8','the','learning','module','5'] 
x = filter(lambda i: not str.isdigit(i), x)
```

or

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
x = ifilterfalse(str.isdigit, x)
```

Note the second returns an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all integers from the list

```
ls = ['1','introduction','to','molecular','8','the','learning','module','5']
ls_alpha = [i for i in ls if not i.isdigit()]
print(ls_alpha)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use this way to remove items from a list: (edited after comment by THC4k)

```
>>> li = ['1','introduction','to','molecular','8','the','learning','module','5']
>>> for item in li:
        if item.isdigit():
            li.remove(item)

>>> print li
['introduction', 'to', 'molecular', 'the', 'learning', 'module']
```

This will not work since changing a list while iterating over it will confuse the for-loop.
Also, item.isdigit() will not work if the item is a string containing a negative integer, as noted by razpeitia.

Comment: Python really needs a mechanism to prevent people from doing this. It looks like it would work, but it doesnt -- try with `li = ['iterating + removing -> skipping', '4', '5', 'see?']` (deleting 4 will skip the 5, so it remains in the list)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lambdas (and, obviously, recursion), to achieve that (Python 3 needed):

```
 isNumber = lambda s: False if ( not( s[0].isdigit() ) and s[0]!='+' and s[0]!='-' ) else isNumberBody( s[ 1:] )

 isNumberBody = lambda s: True if len( s ) == 0 else ( False if ( not( s[0].isdigit() ) and s[0]!='.' ) else isNumberBody( s[ 1:] ) )

 removeNumbers = lambda s: [] if len( s ) == 0 else ( ( [s[0]] + removeNumbers(s[1:]) ) if ( not( isInteger( s[0] ) ) ) else [] + removeNumbers( s[ 1:] ) )

 l = removeNumbers(["hello", "-1", "2", "world", "+23.45"])
 print( l )
```

Result (displayed from 'l') will be: **['hello', 'world']**

Comment: Well, yes, but it would be trivial to change that code to achieve that behaviour.

Comment: Done, now it handles negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` built-in to get a filtered copy of a list.

```
>>> the_list = ['1','introduction','to','molecular',-8,'the','learning','module',5L]
>>> the_list = filter(lambda s: not str(s).lstrip('-').isdigit(), the_list)
>>> the_list
['introduction', 'to', 'molecular', 'the', 'learning', 'module']
```

The above can handle a variety of objects by using explicit type conversion.  Since nearly every Python object can be legally converted to a string, here `filter` takes a str-converted copy for each member of the_list, and checks to see if the string (minus any leading '-' character) is a numerical digit.  If it is, the member is excluded from the returned copy.

[The built-in functions are very useful.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)  They are each highly optimized for the tasks they're designed to handle, and they'll save you from reinventing solutions.