# Return unique non-digit values in a Python list containing various data types

Tags: python, string, list, boolean, unique

I have a list in the following form:

```
full_list = [1, 2, 5, "string", False, True]
```

I want to return a list containing only the non-digit values, like this:

```
new_list = ["string", False, True]
```

My initial thought is to use the isdigit() method, but that only works for strings. I *could* cast each item in the list as a string, and then call isdigit(), but

```
new_list = [i for i in full_list if not str(i).isdigit()]
```

feels like a longwinded workaround. The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159155/how-to-remove-all-integer-values-from-a-list-in-python) sort-of works, but will remove the boolean values from the final list. Is there a more elegant/simplistic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You could just slice off the first three values: `full_list[3:] == ["string", False, True]`

Comment: Hey #Peter he does not know the array, he is just giving us an example. This piece of data will be dynamic in a program(From what I understood).

Comment: @user5676973 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- you want to discard integers (1, 2, 3) but not strings that represent integers ('1', '2', '3')
- you want each element to be unique in the result (what your title suggests)
- the order does not matter

You could use `set`s. And use `Number` as the class to check, plus check `bool` as well because `True`/`False` are `Number` instances as well.

```
from numbers import Number
full_list = [1, 2, 5, "string", False, True]
set(full_list) - set(
    i in full_list if isinstance(i, Number) and not isinstance(i, bool))
```

`Number` covers floats as well. Your example only has integers but you didn't mention explicitly that all numbers should be integers.

Comment: Is order important?

Answer (score 2):

You could just check for `int` and `bool`, excluding the former but including the latter (which is a subclass of the former):

```
>>> [x for x in full_list if not isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, bool)]
['string', False, True]
```

Comment: and for any type of number you can use `numbers.Number` ABC

Answer (score 0):

You could filter by `type(item) != int` (normally I would use `isinstance` but you don't want to discard the booleans - booleans are subclasses of integers in python):

```
filtered_list = [item for item in full_list if type(item) != int]
```

and then filter duplicates:

```
def uniques(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)


>>> list(uniques(filtered_list))
['string', False, True]
```

---

Or to apply an external library<sup>1</sup> that already has an implementation for uniques:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import Iterable

>>> Iterable([1, 2, 5, "string", False, True]).filter(lambda x: type(x) != int).unique_everseen().as_list()
['string', False, True]

>>> # This time with a duplicate "False"
>>> Iterable([1, 2, 5, "string", False, False, True]).filter(lambda x: type(x) != int).unique_everseen().as_list()
['string', False, True]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure: I'm the author of that [`iteration_utilities` library](https://github.com/MSeifert04/iteration_utilities)

Comment: What's the point of the `uniques` function since in sets all elements are unique anyway?

Comment: @Jérôme It's so you can iterate in order, but filter out the non-unique items, as stored in the set. If you just iterate the set you lose the ordering.

Answer (score -1):

Your method is not suitable for real numbers.
Can this be so?

```
new_list = [i for i in full_list if (type(i) != int) and (type(i) != float)]
```

Comment: why exclude floats? From the question `str.isdigit` is the exclusion criterium and `"1.2".isdigit()` is `False`.

Comment: Then type() does seem to be a viable solution in case you  need to differentiate between a bool and an int in py